# Why do we need to use startWith() in this mat-table-http-request example?

Tags: angular, rxjs, mat-table

In this example:

https://stackblitz.com/angular/jnvmaggpgqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts&fbclid=IwAR16o8lA5LZDxUytHWWSR47l7p4phGlGT64YzWSOvOxtK6Te3LgBxPWsf7g

Why do we need to use startWith()?

Comment: You call to the http only when sorting or change the page. So at first you don't call it (at first you has no data, so no page to change and no sorting data). It's true that you can call to the http in the ngOnInit but this make you repeat code. So you use startWith to start with a null value

Comment: @Eliseo So basically, startWith({}) fakes the occurrence of this.paginator.page event therefore allowing switchMap Observable to fire?

Comment: yes, "execute the subscribe" at first without wait a change happens